# Anyone please explain the meaning of turnover in this pic?

Tags: shares, turnover

[image: turnover]

To my knowledge `turnover` in share market context is number of shares traded divided by total shares outstanding. But in this case the turnover is `$42,919,227` denoted by `$` sign other than a ratio, and I can't figure out how is this number calculated? Even I multiply lowest day price `$6.67` with volume `6,696,258` I get `$44,664,040` which is still larger than aforementioned turnover value. Thanks!

Comment: I'd bet it has to do with how quickly it gets it's product out the door. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inventory_turnover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Business Dictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/turnover.html) has three definitions of "turnover".  When it comes to share dealing, the most likely one is the total value of shares traded on the stock exchange in a given period.

Comment: I think the OP's point is that while that is the "obvious" definition, the numbers don't seem to make sense. With a Turnover of `$42,919,227` and a volume of `6,696,258` shares, the average price-per-share would be `$6.41` (to 2dp), which is _below_ the lowest price shown (`$6.67`).